# How to detect when friends are online?

Tags: facebook, friend, facebook-chat

I want to create a desktop application that notifies me whenever a specific friend comes online. My idea was to use the chat API, but found out that it doesn't support "presence probes," which I suppose are what I need. Any other to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to use the `online_presence` field of the [FQL user table](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user/).

> **`online_presence`**: The user's Facebook Chat status. Returns a string, one of active,
>   idle, offline, or error (when Facebook can't determine presence
>   information on the server side). The query does not return the user's
>   Facebook Chat status when that information is restricted for privacy
>   reasons.

To access this information you will need user to grant `friends_online_presence` permission to your application.